# Project xcode to app android with Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, xcode, cordova

I would like to know if it is possible, using PhoneGap, load the xcode project and so as to have the apk in the same app for Android

Answer (score 0):

for Ios you need xcode to build your ipa file and for android you need eclipse to build you apk file. 
you can not build .apk file using xcode.